# Can't access Admin Panel

Tags: https

In Settings > General, I change my site to be `https://` and now when I go to `/wp-admin` I get a 404 Not Found.

Is there a way I can revert this? I tried Googling but found nothing :(

Comment: Maybe you just try following to add in `wp-config.php` , `define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://yourdomain' );`  and `define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://yourdomain' );` , to see if you have at least access again to the back-end. No idea what you already did before that change or was it 'just' a start. (a try won't harm, and if it is not working you just delete those two lines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot revert this. You will need to export your database via PhpMyAdmin and find all of the "HTTPS" instances and replace them with "HTTP". I would suggest using something like Dreamweaver or Notepad++ to 'find and replace all'. After you have done that, import your database again.

Comment: damn, ok, a fresh re-install it is :(

Comment: I don't think you need to reinstall. Just change the part of the URL back to what you need.

Comment: I'm on IIS, I don't have PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: @rocketman7k , What? I hope you are kidding, **no export needed!**. When you can do an export in phpMyAdmin you can also do a search! Like this: In your database you do a search for `siteurl` which will point you at the `table` `wp_options` and says: `1 match in wp_options`. Do the same with home and the results will show also `1 match in wp_options`.  Click both times, Browse and Edit, make the changes and save. Btw, Dreamweaver was also a joke I hope.

Comment: I reinstalled. All is back to normal now.

Comment: Wow @Charles, I'm just trying to be helpful. I'm glad, however, you are the most expert person on this site. I think you should answer everyone's questions with your same level of kindness. I'll bet then everyone will know how smart you are.

Answer (score 1):

the best way is to login to your database, usually thru PHPmyadmin.

Go to your website's options table and edit the option_value for 'siteurl' and/or 'home' to the URL without https:// (just http://)

Comment: when you change the options in Settings > General, it only changes the siteurl and/or home fields. And/or because there are two fields you can change